# MAC: Root User Not Getting Edit Permissions

Tags: macos, terminal, admin, root, osx-elcapitan

I have authenticated root user as per this tutorial https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012 
and edit menu shows Disable Root User option confirming it is enabled.

I am still getting EACCES errors and have to use sudo. Additionally, even with sudo, I am getting an EACCES error about mkdir in an npm package from a terminal script even though I have universal read and write permissions for the whole folder.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does anybody know what's going on or how I can give myself universal use of the terminal without sudo?

Answer (score 1):

To block malware, resent releases of macOS include [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection), which makes the following directories unwritable except as part of an OS upgrade:

- /System
- /bin
- /sbin
- /usr (except /usr/local, that's writable)
- "many" applications in /Applications

This feature can't be disabled while the system is booted up – it can only be disabled by rebooting off the "recovery" partition using the `csrutil` command:

- Boot your mac holding `Command + R` before the Apple logo appears
- Launch Terminal from the Utilities menu
- Run `csrutil status` to check the status, and `csrutil disable` or `csrutil enable` to change it.
- Reboot to exit the recovery partition

For more details:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html

Comment: I followed instructions. System Integrity Protection status: disabled. But I still can't do anything without sudo.

I would add that to access terminal on the Bootup page after Cmd + R you need to navigate via the top navigation bar.

Comment: What do you mean "can't do anything without sudo"?

Comment: I mean running commands like npm run and npm install always require a sudo despite being root admin and disabling SIP.